# How can I group together rankings by number of users?

Tags: rank, google-bigquery

I have a table which includes the following:

```
ID    evar     event_date   ranking  
1    landing   2019-01-01      1   
1    content   2019-01-02      2  
1    homepage  2019-01-03      3  
2    support   2019-02-01      1  
2    content   2019-02-02      2  
3    content   2019-01-23      1  
3    support   2019-01-24      2
```

etc.

I am trying to map customer journeys, so I've ranked the pages that were visited by date.
I need to find the top journeys on the website - so it needs to be at this level, but aggregated by the number of users.

For example: ID 1 made the journey `landing` > `content` > `homepage`;
I would like to see who else made that same journey (without me manually checking)

How can I write such a query?

Answer (score 2):

Your data is not enough to give the query a good test, but this [FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5e4cda0666568dfbdcd4c96d7a98ccd5) seems to do it.

code of dbfille added:

```
SELECT y.journey, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY cnt DESC) as ranking
FROM 
(
    SELECT x.journey, count(*) as cnt
    from 
    (
        SELECT ID, STRING_AGG(RTRIM(evar),',') as journey
        FROM journey
        GROUP BY ID
    ) x
    GROUP BY journey
) y;
```

output:

```
journey,     ranking
content,support,     1
landing,content,homepage,     1
support,content,     1
```

when I add an extra journey like this:

```
INSERT INTO journey VALUES 
(4    ,'landing'   ,'2019-01-01',      1   ),
(4    ,'content'   ,'2019-01-02',      2   ),
(4    ,'homepage'  ,'2019-01-03',      3   );
```

output:

```
**journey,     ranking**
landing,content,homepage,     1
support,content,     2
content,support,     2
```